# using POWER() function in SQL SERVER 2012 causing Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type float

Tags: sql, t-sql, math, sql-server-2012

I am trying to do the following calculation:

```
DECLARE @X Decimal(18,6);
DECLARE @Y Decimal(20,16);

SET @X = 0.002700;
SET @Y = 0.0027770000000000;

SELECT 200 * ( POWER(@Y, ( -1 / ( 2 * @X ))) - 1 );
```

However this results in:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type float.

I have tried casting to float but to no avail.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A float data type can store a maximum value of about 1.79E+308, but the result of this expression is approximately 5.16E+475. See http://tinyurl.com/oy7deu8

Answer (score 1):

May be there is a way to do this. You are trying to calculate `@y power (-1/2*@x)`. This is equivalent to calculating `e power (log(y)*(-1/2x))`.

You could calculate it as

```
select 200 * POWER(2.718281828, log(@Y) * (-1/(2*@X)))
```

Note that `LOG` by default calculates the natural logarithm of the number. And `e` = 2.718281828

Comment: That didn't work either. I found that the value for @y was wrong. However the limitation of the tSQL POWER() function still stands.